AttributeError on Tkinter ttkbootstrap
So I was coding this app using tkinter ttk bootstrap. It works fine on the main window, but when I try to print the results of my function in a new window, it says
AttributeError: 'str' object has not attribute 'get'

I am completely new to coding, so I would appreciate any help.
Here's the code:
from tkinter import*
from ttkbootstrap.constants import*
import ttkbootstrap as tb


root=tb.Window(themename="cosmo")

root.title("UAM Simple Evaluator")
root.geometry("1000x500+180+10")

frame1=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light",borderwidth=0)
frame1.pack(pady=18,padx=18)
label1=tb.Label(frame1,text="Welcome to UAM Simple Evaluator!", font=("BrushScript",   24),bootstyle=("light,INVERSE"))
label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

paralabel2="""UAM Simple Evaluator utilizes the uniformly accelerated motion formulas 
to return users with their desired physical quantities. In order to use it, 
please input the numerical values of the known variables and 
enter 'unknown' for the unknown variables below."""
frame2=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle="light")
frame2.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
label2=tb.Label(frame2,text=paralabel2,font= ("ComicSans",18),wraplength=900,borderwidth=0,bootstyle=('light,INVERSE'),justify='center')
label2.pack(pady=10,padx=1,fill="both")

frame3=tb.Frame(root,bootstyle='light')
frame3.pack(pady=5,padx=10)               
frame3.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame3.columnconfigure(1,weight=8)
frame3.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
frame3.columnconfigure(5,weight=2)                           

S=tb.StringVar(frame3)
U=tb.StringVar(frame3)
V=tb.StringVar(frame3)
A=tb.StringVar(frame3)
T=tb.StringVar(frame3)

S_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Displacement(m)", font=("Arial", 16))
S_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=S)

U_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Initial Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
U_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=U)
             
V_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Final Velocity(m/s)", font=("Arial", 16))
V_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=V)

A_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Acceleration(m/s^2)", font=("Arial", 16))
A_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=A)
             
T_label=tb.Label(frame3, text="Time(s)", font=("Arial", 16))
T_entry=tb.Entry(frame3, font=("Arial",16),textvariable=T)

def UAM_Eval():
  global S
  global U
  global V
  global A
  global T
  if S.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
   S='((float(U.get())+float(V.get()))*float(T.get()))/2'
   A='(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(T.get())'
   S1=round(eval(S),2)
   A1=round(eval(A),2)
   print("The value of the distance is",(S1))
   print("The value of the acceleration is",(A1))
  elif S.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
   S2='(float(U.get())*float(T.get()))+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2)'
   V='float(U.get())+(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))'
   S3=round(eval(S2),2)
   V1=round(eval(V),2)
   print("The value of the distance is",S3)
   print("The value of the final velocity is",V1)
  elif S.get()=='unknown' and U.get()=='unknown':
   S4='(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))-(float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2'
   U='float(V.get())-(float(A.get())*float(T.get()))'
   S5=round(eval(S4),2)
   U1=round(eval(U),2)
   print("The value of the distance is",S5)
   print("The value of the initial velocity is",U1)
  elif S.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
   S6='((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(A.get()))'
   T='(float(V.get())-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())'
   S7=round(eval(S6),2)
   T1=round(eval(T),2)
   print("The value of the distance is",S7)
   print("The value of the time is",T1)
  elif U.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
   U2='((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(V.get())'
   A2='(-2*(float(S.get())-(float(V.get())*float(T.get()))))/(float(T.get())**2)'
   U3=round(eval(U2),2)
   A3=round(eval(A2),2)
   print("The value of the initial velocity is",(U3))
   print("The value of the acceleration is",(A3))
  elif U.get()=='unknown' and V.get()=='unknown':
   U4='(float(S.get())-((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())'
   V2='(float(S.get())+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2))/float(T.get())'
   U5=round(eval(U4),2)
   V3=round(eval(V2),2)
   print("The value of the initial velocity is",U5)
   print("The value of the final velocity is",V3)
  elif U.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
   U6='((float(V.get())**2)-(2*(float(A.get())*float(S.get()))))**(1/2)'
   U7=round(eval(U6),2)
   T2='(float(V.get())-float(U7))/float(A.get())'
   T3=round(eval(T2),2)
   print("The value of the initial velocity is",U7)
   print("The value of the time is",T3)
  elif V.get()=='unknown' and A.get()=='unknown':
   V4='((2*float(S.get()))/float(T.get()))-float(U.get())'
   A4='((2*(float(S.get())-(float(U.get())*float(T.get())))))/(float(T.get())**2)'
   V5=round(eval(V4))
   A5=round(eval(A4))
   print("The value of the final velocity is",V5)
   print("The value of the acceleration is",A5)
  elif V.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
   V6='((float(U.get())**2)+(2*float(A.get())*float(S.get())))**(1/2)'
   V7=round(eval(V6),2)
   T4='(float(V7)-float(U.get()))/float(A.get())'
   T5=round(eval(T4),2)
   print("The value of the final velocity is",V7)
   print("The value of the time is",T5)
  elif A.get()=='unknown' and T.get()=='unknown':
   A6='((float(V.get())**2)-(float(U.get())**2))/(2*float(S.get()))'
   T6='(2*float(S.get()))/(float(U.get())+float(V.get()))'
   A7=round(eval(A6),2)
   T7=round(eval(T6),2)
   print("The value of the acceleration is",A7)
   print("The value of the time is",T7)

def result_printer():

  result_window=tb.Toplevel(root)

  result=UAM_Eval()

  resultL=tb.Label(result_window,text="result")



Calc_btn=tb.Button(frame3, text="Calculate", command=UAM_Eval, width=20)
result_btn=tb.Button(frame3,text="Next Page",command=result_printer,width=20,bootstyle="info")


S_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
S_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
U_label.grid(row=1,column=0)                 
U_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tb.W)                
V_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
V_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
A_label.grid(row=3,column=0)
A_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
T_label.grid(row=4,column=0)
T_entry.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=tb.W)
Calc_btn.grid(row=5,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=tb.N)
result_btn.grid(row=8,column=1,)


root.mainloop()

I just want to print the results on a new window or a new page. I don't know why it is doing that.

Don't overwrite variables S, U, V, A and T inside UAM_Eval().

Also you don't need to use eval() at all.

what can I use instead of eval()?

Just turn the string to expression, for example S2='(float(U.get())*float(T.get()))+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2)' to S2=(float(U.get())*float(T.get()))+((float(A.get())*(float(T.get())**2))/2), and then S3=round(S2,2).

ok, I have removed it. How do I fix the attribute error tho?

Did you understand my first comment?

Thank you soooo much. I changed the variables and that has fixed the problem.

Turns out, I needed to place the first window's code beneath the function.
